# Setting http_servers varaible in .condarc produces yaml.scanner.ScannerError

Tags: anaconda, conda

I created .condarc file setting up http_servers as mentioned [here](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/config.html#configure-conda-for-use-behind-a-proxy-server-proxy-servers), , but when I invoke `conda info` it gives out the following output:

```
C:\Users\[...]\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3>conda info
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[...]\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 4, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\[...]\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 106, in main
    from conda.cli import conda_argparse
  File "C:\Users\[...]\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 15, in <module>
    from conda.cli import common
  File "C:\Users\[...]\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\common.py", line 13, in <module>
    import conda.config as config
  File "C:\Users\[...]\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\config.py", line 106, in <module>
    rc = load_condarc(rc_path)
  File "C:\Users\[...]\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\config.py", line 104, in load_condarc
    return yaml.load(open(path)) or {}
  File "C:\Users\[...]\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yaml\__init__.py", line 72, in load
    return loader.get_single_data()
  File "C:\Users\[...]\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yaml\constructor.py", line 35, in get_single_data
    node = self.get_single_node()
  File "C:\Users\[...]\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yaml\composer.py", line 36, in get_single_node
    document = self.compose_document()
  File "C:\Users\[...]\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yaml\composer.py", line 55, in compose_document
    node = self.compose_node(None, None)
  File "C:\Users\[...]\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yaml\composer.py", line 84, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
  File "C:\Users\[...]\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yaml\composer.py", line 133, in compose_mapping_node
    item_value = self.compose_node(node, item_key)
  File "C:\Users\[...]\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yaml\composer.py", line 84, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
  File "C:\Users\[...]\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yaml\composer.py", line 127, in compose_mapping_node
    while not self.check_event(MappingEndEvent):
  File "C:\Users\[...]\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yaml\parser.py", line 98, in check_event
    self.current_event = self.state()
  File "C:\Users\[...]\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yaml\parser.py", line 428, in parse_block_mapping_key
    if self.check_token(KeyToken):
  File "C:\Users\[...]\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yaml\scanner.py", line 116, in check_token
    self.fetch_more_tokens()
  File "C:\Users\[...]\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yaml\scanner.py", line 257, in fetch_more_tokens
    self.get_mark())
yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning for the next token
found character '\t' that cannot start any token
  in "C:\Users\[...]\.condarc", line 3, column 1
```

Here is my environment:

```
             platform : win-64
        conda version : 3.14.1
  conda-build version : 1.14.1
       python version : 3.4.3.final.0
     requests version : 2.7.0
     root environment : C:\Users\[...]\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3  (writable)
  default environment : C:\Users\[...]\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3
     envs directories : C:\Users\[...]\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs
        package cache : C:\Users\[...]\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\pkgs
         channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/
                        https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/
                        https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64/
                        https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/
```

Appreciate any comments/hints.

Comment: this is more a bug report than a question. There's a bug-tracker on github for that.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a user error.

Answer (score 15):

You've got a TAB character in your yaml file. Replace it with spaces.

Comment: TAB was my  problem too. Thanks @faph

Comment: That error was so frustrating ‍♂️, thanks @faph!

Answer (score 1):

Try `type .condarc` or `cat .condarc`.

`C:\Users\manoj>type .condarc`

channels:

- anaconda-fusion
- defaults

on

- defaults

Edit `.condarc` file to remove last 2 lines in a Text Editor and saved the file. So the .condarc file content should be `-`

channels:

- anaconda-fusion
- defaults

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow :) I made some edits (that will be soon applied) so that your post is correctly displayed using Markdown specifications. Please check that I did not alter the content of your message by editing.